# My Xcode 9 is continuously indexing after an archive. I am not able to build the build

Tags: xcode

I am facing this issue in Xcode 9 - beta, where the Xcode is continuously indexing and not allowing the build to go in my device. Any suggestion?[image]

Comment: Restart xcode and wait....

Comment: Try using the  `Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=400` flag in build settings. See [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274982/xcode-9-2-is-re-indexing-from-scratch-each-time-i-open-it-even-if-nothing-chang/49990184#49990184)